# Getting Null pointer exception when declaring Webdriver as null outside the method and also declaring webdriver inside the method

Tags: selenium, nullpointerexception

Can some one explain why i am getting Null pointer exception when code execution reaches login() method in below script

```
public class TC_01_CreateEmployee {

WebDriver driver=null;

public void launchBrowser() throws Exception
{
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}


public void login()
{
    driver.get("******");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername")).sendKeys("****");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("****");
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
}
```

Comment: To be clear: when executing "WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();" the next statement throws a null pointer exception on driver? That's very unlikely.

Comment: WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(); - This driver has a scope only within the method. The driver object which is used on the login method is still null.

Comment: Thankyou..It helps.

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(); - This driver has a scope only within the method. The driver object which is used on the login method is still null. I am not sure why you would need 2 driver objects. you have 2 options to solve this,

```
public void launchBrowser() throws Exception
{
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    this.driver = driver;
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

Or

```
public void launchBrowser() throws Exception
{
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

Comment: I didn't catch the fact launchBrowser() defines a local variable. Glazed right over it.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the `launchBrowser()` method is not being called before the `login()` method is being called.

An easy way around this is to define a `getDriver()` method that calls `launchBrowser` if `driver` is null.

```java
private WebDriver getDriver() {
    if (driver == null) {
        launchBrowser();
    }

    return driver;
}
```

Then your `login` method looks like:

```java
WebDriver driver = getDriver();

driver.get("******");
driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername")).sendKeys("****");
driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("****");
driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
```